# fadeIn and fadeOut functions not working

Tags: javascript

I am working on fadein and fadeout functions using pure javascript, here is the code:

```
(function() {
    var fx = {
        easing: {
            linear: function(progress) {
                return progress;
            },
            quadratic: function(progress) {
                return Math.pow(progress, 2);
            },
            swing: function(progress) {
                return 0.5 - Math.cos(progress * Math.PI) / 2;
            },
            circ: function(progress) {
                return 1 - Math.sin(Math.acos(progress));
            },
            back: function(progress, x) {
                return Math.pow(progress, 2) * ((x + 1) * progress - x);
            },
            bounce: function(progress) {
                for (var a = 0, b = 1, result; 1; a += b, b /= 2) {
                    if (progress >= (7 - 4 * a) / 11) {
                        return -Math.pow((11 - 6 * a - 11 * progress) / 4, 2) + Math.pow(b, 2);
                    }
                }
            },
            elastic: function(progress, x) {
                return Math.pow(2, 10 * (progress - 1)) * Math.cos(20 * Math.PI * x / 3 * progress);
            }
        },
        animate: function(options) {
            var start = new Date;
            var id = setInterval(function() {
                var timePassed = new Date - start;
                var progress = timePassed / options.duration;
                if (progress > 1) {
                    progress = 1;
                }
                options.progress = progress;
                var delta = options.delta(progress);
                options.step(delta);
                if (progress == 1) {
                    clearInterval(id);
                    options.complete();
                }
            }, options.delay || 10);
        },
        fadeOut: function(element, options) {
            var to = 1;
            this.animate({
                duration: options.duration,
                delta: function(progress) {
                    progress = this.progress;
                    return fx.easing.swing(progress);
                },
                complete: options.complete,
                step: function(delta) {
                    element.style.opacity = to - delta;
                }
            });
        },
        fadeIn: function(element, options) {
            var to = 0;
            this.animate({
                duration: options.duration,
                delta: function(progress) {
                    progress = this.progress;
                    return fx.easing.swing(progress);
                },
                complete: options.complete,
                step: function(delta) {
                    element.style.opacity = to + delta;
                }
            });
        }
    };
    window.fx = fx;
})()
```

I am using the following code to activate the function:

```
document.getElementById('in').addEventListener('click', function() {
    FX.fadeIn(document.getElementById('type'), {
        duration: 2000,
    });
}, false);
```

But when I load the page I get an error with the activation code.

Does anyone know what I have done wrong?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Your global fx object is called `fx` but you are trying to call `FX`. That probably doesn't help.

Comment: Is there a good reason as to why you are trying to basically re-invent part of jQuery?

Comment: @Nunners I like doing things myself, I could use jQuery but this way I have a challenge.

Comment: @Nunners I bet jQuery wasn't the first one doing this but reinvented from another. There could be many good reasons to (re)implement this functionality: for a challenge, for performance... Who cares?

Comment: @jackflash I wasn't disputing that, I was just curious as to what his motive was behind doing this and not using something that has this functionality and is in wide-spread use. I now understand why he wanted to do it and accept that :)

Comment: @Nunners It's OK. I've run into many "library-talibans" along my way and those people really grind my gears :)

Comment: You need to break the problem into smaller pieces, then deal with them one at a time.

Comment: @CodeApprentice: Did you notice the unwaanted comma `,` after `duration: 2000`?

Answer (score 11):

With a few adjustments, your code should work fine...

1. As [Richard Dalton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/338208/richard-dalton) noticed, call the object with `fx` not `FX`.
2. Add default values for all options in case an option isn't provided (your example code throws an error because `options.complete` is undefined). Example:

   ```
   this.animate({
       duration: options.duration || 1000,
       ...
       complete: options.complete || function() { },
       ...
   });
   ```
3. Adjust the styles before animating (imagine an element is hidden using `display: none` instead of `opacity: 0`)... Example (for `fadeIn`):

   ```
   element.style.opacity = 0;
   element.style.visibility = "visible";
   element.style.display = "block";
   ```
4. Check if an action is needed at all (e.g. call to `fadeIn` despite element already being visible):

   ```
   isVisible: function(element) {
       return element.style.display !== "none" && 
               element.style.visibility !== "hidden" && 
               element.style.opacity !== "0";
   }

   // In fadeIn:
   if (!this.isVisible(element)) {
       ...
   }
   ```

Here's the corrected code with an example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VPNxx/)

Certainly one could tweak this a little further, deal with some corner cases (e.g. what happens if there is a call to `fadeIn` while the element is currently being faded out?), and I'm pretty sure it doesn't work in all browsers (old IEs)... But I hope I pointed you in the right direction. :)